# How many legal wives does Winston Blackmore have?

Tags: marriage

On wikipedia it says Winston's father only had one legal wife:

*Anne Mae was the first of Ray's six wives, and the only wife he was legally married to.*

Winston's father only had one "formal wife", the one on the marriage certificate. So I assume that Winston might also only have one legal wife and one legal marriage certificate? If he only has one legal wife, how could he be arrested for polygamy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The law does not criminalize "having more than 1 legal spouse", it criminalizes specific behavior. The polygamy statute is [here](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-293.html). It says

> Every one who (a) practises or enters into or in any manner agrees or
>   consents to practise or enter into (i) any form of polygamy, or (ii)
>   any kind of conjugal union with more than one person at the same time,
>   whether or not it is by law recognized as a binding form of marriage,
>   or (b) celebrates, assists or is a party to a rite, ceremony, contract
>   or consent that purports to sanction a relationship mentioned in
>   subparagraph (a)(i) or (ii),  is guilty of an indictable offence and
>   liable to imprisonment for a term not exceeding five years.

That is, if you behave like you're married to multiple women, you've committed a crime.

Comment: Is "if you behave like you're married to multiple women, you've committed a crime" really true? I think many if not all of the 21st century Americans are having sex with more than one people. How does the court differentiate between "wives" and "cohabitants (concubines)"? Note the common definition of cohabitants: to live together as if married (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cohabitants).

Comment: One salient example is Hugh Hefner, who lived with at least three women at the same time

Comment: Without a trial transcript, we can only conjecture about the logic behind the guilty verdict. I suspect that he did not deny enter into polygamy, and the real issue was the constitutionality of the law.

Comment: @HighGPA citation for "many if not all of the 21st century Americans are having sex with more than one people"?

Comment: @Zymus Only 20% of American men and 30% of American woman had one or less partner. By the way: https://www.healthline.com/health/healthy-sex/average-number-of-sexual-partners#is-that-really-true

Comment: @HighGPA I don't dispute that most Americans have had more than one partner. You said "many if not all of the 21st century Americans are having sex with more than one people", which reads more along the lines of actively engaging in polygamy, which seems to match with the following question "How does the court differentiate between "wives" and "cohabitants (concubines)"? Apologies if we both mean the same thing.

Comment: @Zymus It is very tricky. Many people do have multiple active sexual partners at the same time; dating multiple persons at a time is not a normal but totally acceptable by the society. For example if you call up your ex (who friendly broke up with you because of external reason) or previous 419 partners, I believe at least a fraction of them would be willing to have another night with you; this way you are practically having multiple partners at the same time.

Comment: @Zymus For related evidences, about 20% married spouse cheat and the majority of voters on "https://pairedlife.com/dating/Is-dating-multiple-people-cheating" think that dating multiple person is not cheating and they don't have to inform their partners. I voted for the third by the way.

Comment: Canadians are not Americans and have different legal rights. And, the notion that people don't commit crimes, or are not prosecuted for every crime that they commit, is laughable. Often prosecutors intentionally decide to not enforce whole classes of crimes for long periods of time because they aren't viewed as serious.

Comment: @HighGPA I don't know, seems like a lot of redirecting, stretching, generalizations, and very loose definitions being thrown around.